# How to get maximum value in inner array elements in php

Tags: php, arrays, algorithm, search

This might be very easy to someone but not for me

I have `var_dump($array)` like this.

```
array (size=12)
0 => int 1 
1 => int 7
2 => int 8
3 => int 9
4 => int 3
5 => int 8
6 => int 3
7 => int 6
8 => int 5
9 => int 3
10 => int 4
11 => int 5
```

I need the max value from index  2 to 5 and from index 4 to 8 and from 8 to 11

How can I acheive this. I tried `max()` function but getting errors.

Comment: Iam no getting why someone is downvoted my question here? am I did any mistake in posting the question incorrectly

Comment: I don't give downvotes but I might know the reason. The question is too trivial. If you play with array you will get the solution within 4-5 hours by yourself. Instead you posted a simple problem without giving your best effort. Also to improve question quality you need to show what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate through the array searching the max value. First you set the var `$max` with a negative value and inside the loop if the value in the index `$i` is greater than the `$max`, you change the value.

```
<?php

$array = array(
0 =>  1, 
1 =>  7,
2 =>  8,
3 =>  9,
4 =>  3,
5 =>  8,
6 =>  3,
7 =>  6,
8 =>  5,
9 =>  3,
10 =>  4,
11 =>  5
);

function maxArray($from, $to, $array) {
    $max = -1;
    for($i = $from; $i <= $to; $i++) {
        if($array[$i] > $max) {
            $max = $array[$i];
        }   
    }

    return $max;
}       

echo maxArray(2, 5, $array) . "<br>";
echo maxArray(4, 8, $array) . "<br>";
echo maxArray(8, 11, $array) . "<br>";

?>
```

Output:

```
9
8
5
```

Comment: Thanks for this idea @Adrian but I like with Simple code.

Comment: What if the array contains negative integers?

Comment: @mpen in this case you chose as $max the max negative value

Comment: @mpen you can do this: $max = PHP_INT_MAX * -1

Comment: @AdrianCidAlmaguer FYI, `PHP_INT_MIN === ~PHP_INT_MAX !== PHP_INT_MAX * -1`.

Comment: @mpen thanks for the info

Answer (score 3):

```
max(array_slice($arr,2,3))
max(array_slice($arr,4,4))
max(array_slice($arr,8,3))
```